# Drawing like Corel Painter pencil in Adobe Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, graphics

Is it possible to do something like `Corel Painter` pencil tool does but with `ActionScript`? High-end precision doesn't required. Sensitivity to pen pressure is optional (but I really don't know may it be related to the simulation process).

I did simple drawing tool with `lineTo` on `MOUSE_MOVE` but it doesn't look like smooth line even if simple `BlurFilter` is applied.

Hints, clues or guide referencies (even with hard math) are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Check if [this](http://www.flashandmath.com/advanced/smoothdraw/) is what you are looking for